# How to remove slashes at beginning of string but not any in the middle

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove only the slashes (forward and backward) that occur at the beginning of the string below, up until the first letter or number. I don't want to remove any slashes in the middle of the string.

string: "\//hello\how\are/you"

looking for result like this: "hello\how\are/you"

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
@"^[/\\]+"
```

It is a very basic pattern:

`^` means start of the string

`[/\\]` is a character class that contains `/` and `\` *(note that you must escape the backslash to not escape the closing square bracket)*

Comment: That's genius! Can you explain to me how that works?

Answer (score 2):

```
string = string.TrimStart('\\', '/');
```

As an added bonus, you need not use a regex for this purpose.